# Where can I ask questions about "operations research"?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Where should questions about operations research be asked? Is cross validated appropriate or are other sites within SE network better suited?

I have had a look at https://www.or-exchange.org/questions/,
but that site does not seem to be terribly active (and, as noted [here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5620/is-there-a-way-to-solicit-cross-validated-users-to-commit-to-a-proposed-operatio), is curently and possibly for ever shut down.)

Comment: Why did you ask this on stats se meta and not maths se meta? Just wondering

Comment: Wella, this Is my Main siste of activity ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**NEWEST UPDATE**: Operations Research Stack Exchange has now graduated from Beta, and is still at https://or.stackexchange.com/

**UPDATE: Operations Research Stack Exchange is now in public Beta** at https://or.stackexchange.com/ . So everyone can now actively participate.

https://www.or-exchange.org/questions/ has been permanently shut down due to SPAMMING. The new Stack Exchange site was chosen as a replacement for it.

Answer (score 14):

I think there is no clear-cut distinction possible. This is something inherent to all interdisciplinary fields (e.g. Systems Biology). For the case of Operational Research I think that only a relatively small number of operational research questions could fit neither on [CV](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) nor on the [Computational Science beta](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/). The website you mention is rather good too (when it is active).

If the question has a relatively clear statistical concept, I would suggest keeping in CV. If the meat of the question is on optimisation (e.g. "*how to express X and Y constraints?*"), I would suggest moving it to [scicomp](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/). Questions without a clear Statistics or Optimisation scope would have to be judged in an individual basis (maybe they should be migrated in [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/), [Economics](https://economics.stackexchange.com/) or [Quant. Finance](https://quant.stackexchange.com/)).

Answer (score 12):

As of April 2019, there's a new proposal [Operations Research and Analytics](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/121892/operations-research) on Area 51.

**Update May 2019**: the proposal has passed the commitment stage, and soon will be in public beta.

**Update April 2020**: [Operations Research](https://or.stackexchange.com/) is open and functioning normally.

Comment: Great! Hope this will finally fly.

Comment: I don't bear this particular proposal any ill-will but there are many good reasons why it's hard to get these proposals accepted. The trade-off between a big site with too much traffic for comfort and a small site with too little of interest to attract many participants is difficult and delicate.

Answer (score 5):

If your question deals with algorithmic components of operations research, then Stack Overflow is another site where it could be on topic. As somebody with a background in OR, I try to be active there in [mathematical-optimization](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematical-optimization); other tags on Stack Overflow that get OR-related questions include [linear-programming](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-programming), [integer-programming](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integer-programming), [nonlinear-optimization](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nonlinear-optimization), [quadratic-programming](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quadratic-programming), ...

Quoting a snippet from [Stack Overflow's help center:](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

> We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in
>   them, but if your question generally covers [...] or a software algorithm
>   [...] then you're in the right place to ask your question!

or-exchange is not part of Stack Exchange, but looking through their user page, some of the users there are big people in the field!

Answer (score 2):

As has been noted, some topics do run "across" sites. I do have a background in OR/MS myself and lo and behold so far I have been on Mathematica.SE and a bit of Stats.SE.

I have specialized on [System Dynamics (SD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_dynamics) which is a systems modeling paradigm introduced mainly by Jay Forrester in the late 50s.

As of a week ago I have proposed a new Stack Exchange site in [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) which I have called [**Modeling and Simulation**](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/95927/business-simulation-and-modeling?referrer=F_RkKhnRJ6zHEOEwzGGm6g2). The core criteria for that site in my opinion are:

- use of *models* (which includes conceptual models not only quantitative models)
- and/or use of *computer simulation* typically (but not exclusively) using common paradigms like System Dynamics (SD), Discrete Event Simulation (DES) or Agent-based Modeling (ABM)
- *supporting decision making* in management of a complex system (e.g. some link to optimal control)

It is of course all fresh but instead of running around on very specialized sites there is merit I believe to have a dedicated page for **Modeling and Simulation for Decision Support**. Especially since pages dedicated to OR/MS, or System Dynamics and other topics in this area are often raising too little interest.

Maybe that is a site for you (and hopefully others) to help grow?

---

### Update

As of today I have created a proposal for [**Management Science**](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/98921/management-science?referrer=F_RkKhnRJ6xMlbSbLunD4A2) on Area 51 which I feel is somewhat lacking -- and which has an even broader focus than Modeling and Simulation.

Comment: I just added a [Community Promotion Ad](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/a/3056/36678) for the proposal.

Comment: Update 27 April 2019: Neither proposal got airborne, but see the similar proposal referred to  by @Marcus Ritt.